# Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$planCacheStats'

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregate

Getting the below error when I run the following aggregate commands on MongoDB version 4.0.12. From what I read about the error, it looks like a syntax issue. But this was given to me by someone and they said it works. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
db.bookings.aggregate( [ { $planCacheStats: { } } ] )

db.bookings.aggregate( [ { $planCacheStats: { } } , { $project: {createdFromQuery: 1, queryHash: 1 } } ] )
```

Output:

```
E QUERY    [js] Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$planCacheStats'",
    "code" : 40324,
    "codeName" : "Location40324"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:536:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:620:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:260:9
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1062:12
@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: what version of mongo are you using?

Comment: 4.0.12, sorry for not mentioning that in the post. Let me add it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using version 4.0, it is not supported. So you are getting `unrecognised pipeline error`

> `$planCacheStats` - New in version 4.2

Hence it is Supported from 4.2.

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/planCacheStats/)